# android Listview listen to header view y position changes

Tags: android, listview, header

I m looking to fire some function when the listview header view top edge appears on the phone.
How can you listen to header view y axis position changes ?

Comment: Use the listView onScrollListener to see if you are the top of the firstVisibleItem

Answer (score 1):

```
lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        private int lastFirstVisibleItem;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if(lastFirstVisibleItem<firstVisibleItem)
            {
                Log.i("SCROLLING DOWN","TRUE");
            }
            if(lastFirstVisibleItem>firstVisibleItem)
            {
                Log.i("SCROLLING UP","TRUE");
            }
            lastFirstVisibleItem=firstVisibleItem;

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

      boolean topOfFirst = listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
      if (topOfFirst) {
          //Do something
      }

    }

}
```

The header should take position 0 in a ListView so the boolean will be set to true when the top of position 0 is visible.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way. You can use view.getTop() and view.getBottom() , in this case the view will be the inflated list header.

Comment: If you have found a solution please mark it as the answer.

Comment: if only SO allows me accept my ans before 18 hours ;)